# StackOverFlowException when updating LINQ record w/ self-referencing table

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am getting a StackOverflowException when I update a record with custom/non-database properties in it.  These properties look at database properties, and most importantly, the values in an associated record.

The associated record is the problem - TaskTemplateRecord's set spins off into oblivion.

If I just return 0 here, everything is fine.  I think the below is calling TaskTemplateRecord over and over again.  I just can't figure out why.

How do I fix this?  Is there a way I can tell LINQ to skip properties like this during an update operation?

```
            if (this == new ProjectTask()) return 0;
```

Is there a way to compare the above on values easily?  That may work too.

```
    public int UnitTypeId
    {
        get
        {
            //return 0;

            //If this is a task template return the actual database value
            if (IsTaskTemplate)
                return UnitTypeIdPrivate;
            //If there is a task template override and UnitTypeId has a value return that
            else if (IsTemplateOverride && UnitTypeIdPrivate != 0)
                return UnitTypeIdPrivate;

            //Else return the value in the task template record.
            return (TaskTemplateRecord ?? new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId;
        }
        set { UnitTypeIdPrivate = value; }
    }
```

This is where the StackOverFlowException is getting thrown.

```
    public ProjectTask()
    {
            ...
            this._ProjectTasksUsingThisTemplate = new EntitySet<ProjectTask>(new Action<ProjectTask>(this.attach_ProjectTasksUsingThisTemplate), new Action<ProjectTask>(this.detach_ProjectTasksUsingThisTemplate));
            ...
            }
```

Thanks as always for your help!

Comment: Looks like in some scenario, UnitTypeId property is called over and over again.

Comment: I think TaskTemplateRecord's is being called over and over again.  Not sure why.  I am not calling the set operator anywhere.

Comment: Except that if I just have the property return 0 at the top things work fine...

Comment: (new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId returns (new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId which returns (new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId which returns (new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId which returns (new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this line might be the problem:

```
return (TaskTemplateRecord ?? new ProjectTask()).UnitTypeId;
```

I'm guessing at which class the code you've shown lives in. If `UnitTypeId` is a property of the `ProjectTask` class, then you're creating a new `ProjectTask` here if `TaskTemplateRecord` is null, and it'll keep creating new classes, eventually causing the `StackOverflowException`.

Perhaps this approach will work:

```
if (TaskTemplateRecord != null)
    return TaskTemplateRecord.UnitTypeId;
else
   return 0; // some default value rather than creating the class again
```

Comment: Thank you.  Seems really obvious now.  Those are always the best answers.